# libuuid1-devel package is missing for SLES 12 on Power8

Tags: uuid, powerpc, sles

I am trying to build my application on a SLES 12 on Power8 server (ppc64le).
My application uses libuuid to generate unique identifiers, and my build fails because the libuuid libraries and include files are missing.

I searched for the devel package for libuuid and it is not available on the SLES12 installation DVDs, on the SUSE [website](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=12&architecture=ppc&package_name=index_group), or other rpm search sites.
I looked for the following packages -

libuuid-devel

libuuid1-devel

e2fsprogs-devel

util-linux-devel

Do you know where i can find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the libuuid-devel package, along with other devel packages, on the SLE 12 SDK DVD - https://download.novell.com/protected/Summary.jsp?buildid=eHNDsyWlokA~